# Elasticsearch order query does not order correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm using python to access elasticsearch index. I have one group of data that I want to order by their key value. When I ordered them result does not seem correct one.

This is my query that I send to my index:

```
            "aggs": {
                "Group1": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "method.keyword",
                        "include": ".*POST.*",
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "Group2": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "keyword.keyword",
                                "size": 11593,
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "Group3": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "amount.keyword",
                                        "size": 100,
                                        "order": {"_key": "desc"}

                                    }
                                }

                            },
                        }
                    },



                }

            }
```

This is what the query has returned:

```
"aggregations": {
    "Group1": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "Group2": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "Group3": {
                  "buckets": [
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "9"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "89"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "88"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "87"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "86"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "85"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "84"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "83"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "82"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "81"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "80"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "8"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "79"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "78"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "77"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "76"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "75"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "74"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "73"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "72"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "71"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 1, 
                      "key": "70"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "7"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "69"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "68"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "67"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "66"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "65"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "64"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "63"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "62"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "61"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "60"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "6"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "59"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "58"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "57"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "56"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "55"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "54"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "53"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "52"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "51"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "50"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 3, 
                      "key": "5"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "49"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "48"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "47"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "46"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "45"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "44"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "43"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "42"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "41"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "40"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 3, 
                      "key": "4"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "39"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "38"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "37"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "36"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "35"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "34"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "33"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "32"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "31"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "30"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 3, 
                      "key": "3"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "29"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "28"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "27"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "26"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "25"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "24"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "23"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "22"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "21"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "20"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 3, 
                      "key": "2"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "19"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "18"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "17"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "16"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "15"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "14"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "13"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "12"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "11"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 2, 
                      "key": "10"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "doc_count": 6, 
                      "key": "1"
                    }
                  ], 
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0
                }, 
                "doc_count": 167, 
                "key": "y&price_max"
              },
```

As you see, the key value didn't ordered correctly. How can I order it?

Comment: amount.keyword is a string value so it has sorted them alphabetically. If you want a numeric sort you need to use a numeric field.

Comment: What kind of query I need to make if I convert that amount data to integer?

Comment: Got it. I need to remove keyword part from "amount.keyword". Thank you sir.

Comment: OK great. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `amount.keyword` is a string value, it has sorted them alphabetically. If you want a numeric sort you need to use a numeric field. For example, if `amount` (without the keyword part) is numeric, use that.